# Auto Calc percentage and Post values in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

i want a sql query which helps me to calculate percentage for all cells in MAX column.

it should calculate like this - (max/500)*100

and it should post all those values in a new row "max_percent"

**SQL Table**

```
id   Name   min    max   max_percent
1  Samsung  100    2050
2  Nokia    100    1520
3  HTC      1200   5600
4  Apple    1200   2210
5  O2       700    1700
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable SET `max_percent`=`max`/500*100
```

Comment: oh you mean create a new `column` ? You can search for `ALTER TABLE` syntax and then first add the field then run the above query